# Commutative operator definition in Scala

Tags: scala

Let's say I define some operators for my class like this:

```
class A {
    def +(f: Float) = /* ... */
}

val a: A = new A
```

This allows me to do `a + 1f`, easy enough. What if I want to enable the lib's user to be able to write `1f + a`, too? How can I implement that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In Scala 2.9 you can import this implicit conversion:

```
implicit def floatPlusAExtender (x: Float) = 
  new {
    def + (a: A) = a + x
  }
```

and use it as you wanted. Since Scala 2.10 you better do this conversion like so:

```
implicit class FloatPlusAExtender (x: Float) {
  def + (a: A) = a + x
}
```

or even better like so:

```
implicit class FloatPlusAExtender (val x: Float) extends AnyVal {
  def + (a: A) = a + x
}
```

The last way is called [Value Class](http://docs.scala-lang.org/sips/pending/value-classes.html) and in difference to preceding two it provides this functionality with zero overhead. (Thanks, axel22) This is also the new stuff that comes with 2.10

Or you can just modify `A` like so:

```
class A {
  def + (x: Float) = /* ... */
  def +: (x: Float) = this + x
}
```

and use it like so:

```
1f +: a
```

The last approach is preferable.

Comment: whe exactly is it preferable?

Comment: It is an idiomatic way of writing right-associated operators which are actually just unary (single parameter) methods in scala. Also performance-wise the first approach introduces an overhead of instantiation of a wrapper class

Comment: In Scala 2.10 you can also make the `FloatPlusAExtender` extend `AnyVal` to avoid instantiating a wrapper object.

Comment: @axel22 Is that a Value classes initiative?

Comment: Yes, I am referring to value classes: http://docs.scala-lang.org/sips/pending/value-classes.html

Answer (score 3):

One approach is the [pimp-my-library-pattern](http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=179766):

```
class FloatWithPlusA(f: Float) {
  def +(a: A) = a + f
}

implicit def floatPlusA(f: Float): FloatWithPlusA =
  new FloatWithPlusA(f)

val a: A = new A
a + 1.0f  /* a.+(1.0f) */
1.0f + a  /* floatPlusA(1.0f).+(a) */
```

Another approach is adding a right-associative method, but with the obvious disadvantage that the syntax of the two operators varies:

```
class A {
  val f: Float = 1.0f

  def +(f: Float) = this.f + f
  def +:(f: Float) = this.f + f
}

val a: A = new A
a + 1.0f
1.0f +: a
```